# Why is left outer join failing here for me?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I see nothing wrong here, but why does this give me

```
/* SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'left outer join votes on items.id = votes.parent and votes.userid = 1 group by i' at line 2 */


select maxVotes, sum(case when coalesce(votes.id, 0) then 1 else 0 end) votesCast from items where type = 'marker'
left outer join votes on items.id = votes.parent and votes.userid = 1 group by items.id;
```

I'm doing this using mySql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to

```
select maxVotes, 
       sum(case when coalesce(votes.id, 0) then 1 else 0 end) votesCast 
  from items left outer join votes -- <-- your JOIN clause should go here
    on items.id = votes.parent 
   and votes.userid = 1 
 where type = 'marker' -- <-- and WHERE here
group by items.id;
```

On a side note: even though MySql allows to specify a field (in your case maxVotes) in `SELECT` that is not a part of `GROUP BY` it's a not a good thing to do. You need to apply an aggregate function to that field (`MAX, MIN...`). There is no way to tell which value of `maxVotes` to grab when you do `GROUP BY items.id`.

Answer (score 2):

Move your `JOIN` before `WHERE` clause:

```
select maxVotes, sum(case when coalesce(votes.id, 0) then 1 else 0 end) votesCast
from items
left outer join votes on items.id = votes.parent and votes.userid = 1
where type = 'marker'
group by items.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
select maxVotes, 
       sum(case when coalesce(votes.id, 0) then 1 else 0 end) votesCast 
from items 
left outer join votes on items.id = votes.parent and votes.userid = 1 
where items.type = 'marker' group by items.id;
```